# What versions of OSes and/or its components does Amazon Corretto 8 support?

Tags: corretto

The docs say stuff like "Windows x64", but what does it mean with regards to operating system versions? What Windows Server is it compatible with, for example?

Same thing with "Linux x64", there is no such operating system of course, it all comes down to a particular minimal kernel version requirement, perhaps a minimum `glibc` version or something.

Is this information available anywhere please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windows builds are supported on Windows 7 and 10, and on Windows Server 2008, 2012, and 2016.

Says by official docs on [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-corretto-8-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/windows-info.md)